# Can I have non-html/md files in a rendered collection?

Tags: jekyll

I have a `writing` collection in my Jekyll site, and I have `output` set to true, because I want all the `.md` and `.html` files rendered. However, there are some `.js` and `.css` files as well, which I'd like  Jekyll to just serve up as normal.

I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `data' for #<Jekyll::StaticFile:0x00000104d8bb70>
```

and I believe it's because Jekyll is trying to parse out the js/css files.

Is it possible to have static files served up normally within my collections?

---

**Update** Here's the full trace:

```
Configuration file: project/_config.yml
            Source: project
       Destination: project/_site
      Generating...
Unable to find a valid configuration: sass_path=project/_compass
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.6.2/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:38:in `has_alt_urls?': undefined method `data' for #<Jekyll::StaticFile:0x000001035f8f58> (NoMethodError)
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.6.2/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:14:in `block in generate_alt_urls'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.6.2/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:13:in `each'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.6.2/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:13:in `generate_alt_urls'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-redirect-from-0.6.2/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirector.rb:9:in `generate'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:251:in `block in generate'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:250:in `each'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:250:in `generate'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:45:in `process'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:55:in `build'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:33:in `process'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.4/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.4/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.4/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.4/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.4/lib/mercenary/program.rb:35:in `go'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.4/lib/mercenary.rb:22:in `program'
        from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.4.0/bin/jekyll:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Even in collection folder, .js an .css are not parsed if they don't have front matter. Can you do a **jekyll build --trace** to have more infos ?

Comment: I updated. Why the downvote?

Comment: not me. Look I upvote.

Answer (score 4):

You normally should be able to use static files in collection but there is a jekyll-redirect 0.6.2 bug ([ticket is here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/issues/47)).

### Workarounds

#### 1. use Github pages configuration

If you plan to serve your site from Github pages, you will need to add a `Gemfile` with

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

Then do a `bundle update`. This will resolve the problem as Jekyll-redirect 0.3.1 doesn't try to make redirect for collections.

#### 2. Move your static files

Move your static files out of your collection folder to avoid the bug with collections static files.

#### 3. Remove redirect plugin

If you don't need it or need it just for one or two pages, remove it from you Gemfile and craft needed redirect page by copying redirect pages.

Comment: Been suffering through this issue for about a year now. Sure enough, #2 - Move your static files, solved it for me. Thanks!